# Worth publishing different site languages on different AWS locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-regions

I cannot separate pages dedicated to different regions/languages between AWS buckets in different locations (pages are NOT on separate sub-domains, e.g. **en**.example.com and **de**.example.com, instead, pages are structured as example.com/**en** and example.com/**de**)

So, is it worth placing German sub-pages in a different bucket in Frankfurt AWS region and redirect all requests to example.com/**de** (that is placed under main London region for example.com domain) to the separate bucket? Will location-related ping decrease overweight ping increase caused by redirect call?

Similar question applies to Tokyo, Ireland and Paris regions comparing to the main London one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting out of S3, then I presume all of your content is static.

I would start with using Cloudfront, and if you really wanted to you could have separate languages mapped to separate buckets in different locations - i.e. /de/ could map to a bucket in eu-central-1, /en/ could map to eu-west-2, etc.

However this should have little impact on the performance your end users see, since they should be retrieving content from the nearest edge location.

Comment: Thanks. CloudFront seems exactly to be the solution I need